# Exception when executing agent maintenanceService in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I am utilizing Sitecore 8.0 - Update 4.

I note the following errors occurring once every minute in my log.2010706.??????.txt log files:

```
8620 14:46:15 ERROR Exception when executing agent maintenanceService
Exception: Sitecore.Exceptions.RequiredObjectIsNullException
Message: Could not find add method: RegisterService (type: Sitecore.Analytics.Core.MaintenanceAgent)
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(Object obj, Object[] properties)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.CreateAgent()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.ExecuteAgent()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this and how it can be resolved?

Comment: Is this a fresh install or did you upgrade?

Comment: This was a fresh install.

Comment: Is this on a CD or CM?

Comment: This particular system is a development system which serves as a CD/CM (i.e. it can publish to itself).   The eventual system where I will be deploying analytics will be a CD only.

Answer (score 1):

`MaintenanceAgent` is configured in `Sitecore.Analytics.config` and is a part of `Sitecore.Analytics.Core.dll`. It was introduced in **Sitecore  8.0 rev. 150621** so I'm guessing that you're missing that dll or you have some older version of it.

Can you check if there is `Sitecore.Analytics.Core.dll` in your bin directory and what is its version?

It should be:

[image]

Comment: It is 8.0 rev. 150621 (File Version: 8.0.5193.0, Date Modified:06/21/2015 1:58PM, Size: 47.3 KB)

Comment: Try to compare other dlls in the bin folder with the vanilla Sitecore dlls?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of all the DLLs in the bin folder.   I am not seeing anything obvious:  http://eat-sleep-code.com/images/temp/sitecore-dlls.png